# fgetws segfaults after a few iterations

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a container that holds the Japanese alphabet, so I'm using the data type wchar_t, and have my .c and .txt files encoded in UTF-8. The idea is that the program populates the container by reading in the .txt file. I can read in the first few lines, but after a few iterations the program segfaults. I suspect it is fgetws because of a few wprintf statements that I've put around the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct entry {
    wchar_t romaji[5];
} entry;

typedef struct dictionary {
    struct entry entry[46];
} dictionary;

void init_dictionary(dictionary **dictionary) {
    (*dictionary) = malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
}

void add_romaji(dictionary *dictionary, wchar_t *romaji, int index) {
    entry new;

    wcscpy(new.romaji, romaji);

    dictionary->entry[index] = new;
}

void populate(dictionary *dictionary) {
    FILE *fp;
    wchar_t line[5];
    wchar_t *ptr;
    wchar_t romaji[5];
    int i;

    fp = fopen("romaji.txt", "r");
    i = 0;

    while(fgetws(line, 5, fp) != NULL) {
        wcstok(line, L"\n", &ptr);
        wcscpy(romaji, line);
        add_romaji(dictionary, romaji, i);
        ++i;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    dictionary *dictionary;

    init_dictionary(&dictionary);
    populate(dictionary);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

romaji.txt is in UTF-8, and just contains a line for each character in the Japanese alphabet. I'm unable to get the indentation here to work, so I cannot post it, sorry. I tried searching for an answer, but none have helped. If anyone could let me know what my mistake is, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you copy `line`'s content? just `add_romaji(dictionary, line, i);`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will change it. I'm just a bit more concerned with finding out what is causing the segfault, at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic problem with indiscriminately using `typedef` and naming variables the same as your resulting type.

You need to either change:

```
(*dictionary) = malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
```

to:

```
*dictionary = malloc(sizeof(struct dictionary));
```

or even better, change the whole function to:

```
void init_dictionary(struct dictionary ** dict)
{
    struct dictionary * new_dict = malloc(sizeof *new_dict);
    if ( !new_dict ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *dict = new_dict;
}
```

Right now, you're just allocating memory for a pointer to a pointer to `struct dictionary`, not for an actual `struct dictionary`, and you're segfaulting from whatever undefined behavior overrunning that allocation is leading you to. More likely than not it's trampling on the memory that `fopen()` dynamically allocates, overwriting what your file pointer points to and causing a segfault in your `fgetws()` call.

`typedef` has valid uses, but just saving a few keystrokes isn't one of them, and as often as not will just lead to confusion like this. Save yourself some trouble and just write your `struct` types out in full.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll rework the code and see it goes.